# Getting # value at the end of url in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get the value after # in the following url:

www.google.com/trian/test#dummyvalue

I am using ASP.NET and C#

Comment: by writing code....Or searching...

Answer (score 0):

A web browser won't pass this value back to the server.  So in a typical scenario with a user on their computer accessing your website.  The "fragment" portion of the url won't be supplied to the server.  Therefore, your asp.net code can not access it.  If you change your code to put this data in the querystring, then you can access it server side from asp.net.